# How was the name “Solidity” chosen?

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethereum-classic

Academic and historical interest, how was the name "Solidity" conceived by Gavin Wood. Every name has an interesting history, can't find much on Solidity though. It is based on ECMA script standard, very similar to javascript. But what is the inspiration behind the name "Solidity".

Comment: From the wikipedia page it was the work of Gavin Wood, so you can ask him for the name. [This](https://stackedit.io/viewer#!url=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gavofyork/31b35cd2252a00d0d057/raw/16de06189d2175d2e31b300f1f8531e20c927635/solidity-original) reference mention the name solidity but not their origin.

Comment: @Ismael yes, had pushed it over his linkedin message. Yet to receive any comment. Will try tweets as last resort

Comment: I'd try asking in https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/ or https://gitter.im/ethereum/ some Ethereum developers hang there and they probably know more details.

Answer (score -1):

My guess: When you're programming with money, you need a *Solid* programming language, run-time environment and compiler:

- The execution of the program should be 100% deterministic. It should always run exactly the same way on all systems.
- The language design should make it relatively easy to write good and secure code, and it should make it difficult to write bad and insecure code.
- The compiler should give warnings about potential vulnerabilities in your program.
- Smart contracts, once published, cannot be modified. They are solidly set in stone in the blockchain.
- Nobody should be able to arbitrarily change a state variable of a contract without going through the procedures programmed into the contract.
- The run-time environment and the compiler should be bug-free, tested, reviewed  and audited.

I think these are all aspects of 'being solid' in a computer science sense: *Solidity*

Comment: Thanks for the logical interpretation. However, I am expecting some documentation based naming origin. In simple words, I do not want the inference we can get from the name, I want to know the incident or thought process the founder had while the word triggered. For example, Vitalik states the inspiration for the word Ethereum from physics' ether and science fiction. Hadoop was inspired by toy elephant of founder child. Python was inspired by monty python series. Not the other way around, to fit an explanation after I have a name.

Comment: Down vote because it is a "guess."